# Devolver un valor para la misma fecha del año anterior con power query

Tags: funciones, date, función-personalizada, powerquery, agregación

necesitaría crear en power query una columna en la que se devuelva para el valor para una misma fecha pero del año anterior.

Concretamente tengo los siguientes datos y necesitaría construir la columna que llamo "nueva":

```
Fecha        Deflactor    Nueva Columna
31/03/2014   99,715       
30/06/2014   99,515
30/09/2014   99,273
31/12/2014   99,330
31/03/2015   100,174      99,175
30/06/2015   99,980       99,515
30/09/2015   99,985       99,273
31/12/2015   99,865       99,330
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a saber cómo crear esta columna nueva en Power Query (que no Power BI)?
Gracias

Comment: Mira la respuesta de abajo. No llevo mucho tiempo con Power Query, pero por más que he intentado, directamente no he visto manera de restar los 365 días, ya que PQ no resta a un formato fecha un entero. Al menos no he dado con ello. Pero la solución solo implica crear un campo intermedio, con formato entero de la fecha a tratar y después restarle los 365 días.

Comment: Y, como se ve en el resultado,  funciona para años bisiestos: de 29/02/2024 devuelve 01/03/2023

Answer (score 0):

Una vez tengas la consulta/tabla en Power Query, duplicas la columna: (menú Agregar columna/Duplicar) (yo la he duplicado para verlo más claro, pero se podría hacer directamente sobre el campo fecha a tratar)

Resultado:

```
= Table.DuplicateColumn(_MITABLA, "fecha", "fecha - Copia")
```

Después, se convierte a Entero la fecha. (Eso lo hago para poder jugar con el valor fecha) (Menú Transformar/Tipo de Dato:Entero)

Resultado:

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Columna duplicada",{{"fecha - Copia", Int64.Type}})
```

Después, agregamos Columna Personalizada (Menú Agregar Columna/Columna Personalizada) (Ahí es cuando se le restan 365 días)

Resultado:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Tipo cambiado", "Personalizado", each [#"fecha - Copia"]-365)
```

Por último, para ver la columna con la nueva fecha en formato fecha transformamos el formato del campo. (Menú Tranformar/Tipo de Dato:Fecha)

Resultado:

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personalizada agregada",{{"Personalizado", type date}})
```

Por favor, dado que hace meses que formulaste la pregunta, si te sirvió, finaliza y puntúa la respuesta. Gracias

[image: Y así quedaría]